# small-cone-injectivity in $\mathbf{Grp}$

Tags: category-theory, terminology

I do not understand the role of the **empty graph** in the definition, numbered (5) in the snippet , of a  small-cone-injectivity condition for connected graphs. Is $a\ b$ , the domain of the cone **empty** ? So in other words what is meant by

```
    presented by the unique morphism from the empty graph ?
```

[image]

Comment: What book is this? What is a small cone injectivity class? At any rate the empty graph, much like the empty set, is initial in any sensible definition of a category of graphs

Comment: The book is [here](http://62.182.86.140/main/272000/ab3d9500be6b703329c6533a0ca47dab/%28London%20Mathematical%20Society%20lecture%20note%20series%20189%29%20J.%20Adamek%2C%20J.%20Rosicky%20-%20Locally%20presentable%20and%20accessible%20categories-Cambridge%20University%20Press%20%281994%29.pdf). You may need copy that link into your web browser instead of clicking on it. The name is *Locally presentable and accessible categories* by *Jiri Rosicky and Jiri Adamek*.

Comment: The rest of the sentence is "presented by the unique morphism from the empty graph to any discrete nonempty graph", for example from $\emptyset$ to $K_1$. Its purpose is to exclude the empty graph from the injectivity class. The cone would accept it.

Comment: @MarcOlschok I'm a bit slow. How can I exclude the empty graph by adding $f:\emptyset \to K_1$ and especially **where** should I add this $f$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A graph is connected if it satisfies two conditions: a) that it is non-empty and b) that any pair of vertices is connected by a directed path.

Categorically, condition b) asserts that any graph morphism $a\ b\to G$ where $a\ b$ is the graph with two vertices and no edges factors through a morphism from $a\ b$ to $a\to\bullet\to\cdots\bullet\to b$. Thus condition b) asserts exactly injectivity with respect to the cone with vertex $a\ b$ and components the morphisms from $a\ b$ to $a\to\bullet\cdots\to\bullet\to b$.

Condition a) can also be expressed as injectivity with respect to a cone. First, by definition a graph is non-empty if and only if it has a morphism from the discrete graph with a single vertex. Since the graphs with morphisms to the discrete graph with a single vertex are precisely the discrete graphs, we have that a graph is non-empty if and only if admits a morphism from a non-empty discrete graph.

Fix a particular non-empty discrete graph. Since every graph has a unique morphism from the empty graph, being non-empty thus reduces to asserting that the morphism from the empty graph factors through the morphism from the empty graph to the fixed non-empty discrete graph. Thus condition a) is injectivity with respect to a cone whose vertex is the empty graph and a single component given by the morphism from the empty graph to a non-empty discrete graph. This is what is mean by a "cone presented by the unique morphism to a non-empty discrete graph".

Comment: Good answer. But now we have **two** cones for which we must test injectivity: one on the page 186 from the book and the other whose vertex is $\emptyset$ and target a non-empty discrete graph. But **small-injecitivty-cone** talks just about a **single** cone. How can I merge these two graphs ? These 2 cones do not have a common domain: one is $a b$ and the other $\emptyset$ so they cannot be juxtaposed.

Comment: @user122424 on p.184 defines a cone-injeccivity class to be the collection of objects injective with respect to each cone in a class of cones. In particular, objects injective with respect to both of two cones is an injectivity-class.